# Simple Adding a JLabel to JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have simple problem as I am not much familiar with Java GUI. I am trying to make visible the JLable on the below code as I find it hard to understand the concept. But still label is not visible but the frame do open on run time.

```
public class Sample extends JPanel {

    public void Sample() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("User Name", JLabel.LEFT);
        p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        p.add(lab1 = new JLabel("add JLabel"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Sample());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are forgot to add panel `p` to sample. Either use `add(p)` at the end or just remove panel `p` cause your sample class is extending JPanel.

Option 1:

```
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("User Name", JLabel.LEFT);
    p.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
    p.add(lab1 = new JLabel("add JLabel"));
    add(p);
```

option 2:

```
    JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("User Name", JLabel.LEFT);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
    add(lab1 = new JLabel("add JLabel"));
```

---

Also why are you overriding initialization of JLabel? In your code JLable will always hold value "add JLabel". If you want to see "User Name" then use this `add(lab1);` instead of `add(lab1 = new JLabel("add JLabel"));`.

May be you just require this:

```
    JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("User Name", JLabel.LEFT);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
    add(lab1);
```

---

Also constructor can not have return type so remove void from your constructor.

Comment: Why do you reassign `lab1` with `add(lab1 = new JLabel("add JLabel"));` instead of `add(lab1);`?

Comment: @Tommy: I have asked same thing to OP?

Comment: Thank you very much guys!!! It was a silly mistake to put a void on a constructor. Thanks again Harry.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor that you are using is not a proper constructor .. A java constructor does not have a return type and the `void` is extra.  When in the main method you are calling new Sample() it is not actually calling your method but the default constructor that exists by default.

Try like this ..

```
public Sample() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("User Name", JLabel.LEFT);
    p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p.add(lab1 = new JLabel("add JLabel"));
}
```

also you need to do what @Harry Joy suggested to add the `add(p);` statement otherwise the panel is still not added.

Answer (score 2):

Note the comments.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Sample extends JPanel {

    public Sample() {
        // set the layout in the constructor
        super(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));

        // best not to set size OR preferred size!
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200,200) );

        JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("User Name");
        add(lab1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // construct the GUI on the EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("User Details");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.getContentPane().add(new Sample());
                // important!
                frame.pack();

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Note also, that it is generally not considered a good idea to extend a component unless adding custom functionality.  That would mean (for example) defining new methods for the `Sample` panel (Which might better be labelled a `UserDetails` or `UserDetailsContainer` if I guess correctly where you are going with that code..).  Or it might be a `Login` component..

Comment: Thanks Andrew! :) super(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING)); is a new thing to me I didnt knew how to use super() that now I know how to now. Thanks again..

Comment: @Splitter:  I made a WAG that `FlowLayout.LEADING` was the effect you were trying to achieve by using the `JLabel.LEFT` constraint in the `JLabel` constructor.  It is my habit to supply the layout in the constructor simply because I hate 'wasting' another line of code on it.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sample is the Jpanel.

Sample extends JPanel means you inherit from JPanel.

just drop JPanel p and all your "p."s

Answer (score 0):

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyGui extends JFrame{

```
private MyContentPane myContentPane = new MyContentPane(); 

public MyGui(){
    super("title");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setContentPane(myContentPane);

    this.createMenu();

    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);      
}

private void createMenu(){
    JMenuBar myMenuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu xMenu = new JMenu("x");
    JMenu x = new JMenu("x");

    JMenuItem xItem = new JMenuItem("letter");

    JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("exit");

    xItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            myContentPane.xPanel();
        }
    });
    xItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            myContentPane.setxPanel();
        }
    });

    exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    displayMenu.add(letterItem);
    displayMenu.add(colorItem);

    fileMenu.add(exitItem);

    myMenuBar.add(displayMenu);
    myMenuBar.add(fileMenu);

    this.setJMenuBar(myMenuBar);
}
```

}